# JPA2 One-To-Many Empty Join Table

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to create a one-to-many relationship between Publications and Authors, however for some reason when I persist the Publication, the Authors get persisted, but the Join table is empty.

**Publication.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name="PUBLICATIONID")
private String id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "authorspublication", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Author> authors;
```

**Author.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "AUTHORID")
private String authorid;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Publication.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "authorspublication", referencedColumnName = "publicationid")
private Publication authorspublication;
```

**DataParser.java**

```
//pub is created - non managed
//author is created - non managed

author.setPublication(pub);
pub.getAuthors().add(author);

em.merge(pub);
```

I dont know if owning sides are backwards, or if its something else.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I added the persistence code. The JPA log on deploy throws no errors or warnings. I'll set the detail level to FINE and look again.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. Inserts are executed for all Publications first, then Authors, but the Join Table is never referenced

Comment: Are you using eclipse-link as your JPA provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `@JoinColumn` which indicates you are using a FK column in the authors table to link publications to their authors.

If you want to use a join table you need to remove this and use the `@JoinTable` annotation. However it seems to me that you have your mappings the wrong way round. Surely the relationship is OneToMany from Authors to Publications? For that matter surely an author can have many publications and a publication can have more than one author?

For the scenario posted however it should like:

```
public class Publication{

    @Id
    @Column(name="PUBLICATIONID")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "publications", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Author> authors;
}
```

```
public class Author{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AUTHORID")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "author_publications", joinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHORID"), inverseJoinColumn = @JoinColumn(name = "PUBLICATIONID"))
    private Publication publications;
}
```

However you probably want to change the Publication field in Author to a be a Collection of Publications and replace the `@OnetoMany` with a `@ManyToMany`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined it to use a `@JoinTable`; it is currently using a foreign key hence why no insert into the join table. You need to add

```
@JoinTable
```

to the one to many field (*authors*). Don't forget to remove the `@JoinColumn` since that is for FK relations

Comment: I removed the reference of the entity Publication from Author, and did the join table and that worked. How would I add back in the publication reference in Author and make it bi-directional?

Comment: bidirectional is when you specify "mappedBy", like you had (but remove the JoinColumn)